# fonts changing from http to https

Tags: html, css, http, ssl, https

so i just activated ssl for my website and i noticed that the font changed. It went from League Sparton Bold to something slightly different. It is not exactly what i desire. Here is what i wrote in css

```
<html>
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
      <link href="https://allfont.net/allfont.css?fonts=league-spartan" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><head>
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
      </head>
    <style>
    body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 { font-family: 'League Spartan Bold', arial; }
    body, html {
      height: 100%;
      color: #777;
      line-height: 1.8;
      min-width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

here is what it looks like with http, which is also what i want for https:
[image]
and this is what it looks like in https,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the CSS file which has been linked to by

```
<link href="https://allfont.net/allfont.css?fonts=league-spartan" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Although the actual linking is requested using https, if you look within the file you will see it has:

```
@font-face{font-family:league spartan bold;font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:local('League Spartan Bold'),local('LeagueSpartan-Bold'),url(http://allfont.de/cache/fonts/league-spartan_96d155934eb746bc55706f1589b67f14.woff) format('woff'),url(http://allfont.de/cache/fonts/league-spartan_96d155934eb746bc55706f1589b67f14.ttf) format('truetype')}
```

and so if the font isn't local, it tries to get it from allfont.de but with http

One way of getting over this problem would be to put this code direct into style in your header, altering the two http to https so you aren't dependent on allfont's text.

```
@font-face{font-family:league spartan bold;font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:local('League Spartan Bold'),local('LeagueSpartan-Bold'),url(https://allfont.de/cache/fonts/league-spartan_96d155934eb746bc55706f1589b67f14.woff) format('woff'),url(https://allfont.de/cache/fonts/league-spartan_96d155934eb746bc55706f1589b67f14.ttf) format('truetype')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Embed or import the font from somewhere you can also download the font then use `@font-face` to import it in your site like this:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'League Spartan Bold'; // You can use any name
 src: url(fonts/thefont.ttf) format('TTF') //  The path of the font file
 // You can use many formats like TTF, OTF, WOFF
}
```

So, by this way you can host your own font and don't need to be depended on a third party service (which can be down any time).